# Recuperar string no banco de dados em um form_dropdown dinâmico

Tags: php, codeigniter, formulário, dropdown

Estou tentando recuperar do banco de dados uma string em um campo *dropdown* de um *form* numa página de *update*, a minha *view* segue abaixo.

```
$option = array(NULL => 'Selecione uma categoria');

foreach ($categories_list->result() as $category):

$option[$category->categoryID] = $category->categoryTitle;

endforeach;

echo form_dropdown('categoryname', $option, set_value('categoryname', $post->categoryTitle));
```

No entanto, o *dropdown* não exibe a string do banco. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema que estava localizado nesta linha:

```
$option[$category->categoryID] = $category->categoryTitle;
```

Que corrigi trocando por:

```
$option[$category->categoryTitle] = $category->categoryTitle;
```

E já ficou a funcionar com o código:

```
echo form_dropdown('categoryname', $option, $post->categoryTitle);
```

Na caixa de selecção não tinha os IDs como valor de cada `option` mas sim o texto que é igual à legenda apresentada ao utilizador.

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que vejo no código da tua pergunta, a unica coisa incorrecta é o uso do `set_value()`, se o removeres deverá funcionar como esperado.

**Nota:** o `set_value()` serve para definir o valor de um input regular ou caixa de texto. Não funciona com caixas de selecção.

Podes saber mais no [CodeIgniter: Guia do Utilizador](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

<sup>Está quase no fim da página.</sup>

---

No teu *controller* terás algo do género:

```
$categoriesList = $this->db->get('categories')->result();
```

Depois podes gerar o teu `select` com a ajuda do *helper* `form_dropdown`:

```
$options = array(null => "Selecione uma categoria");

foreach ($categoriesList as $cat) {
    $options[$cat->categoryID]=$cat->categoryTitle;
}

echo form_dropdown('categoryname', $options, $post->categoryTitle);
```

Comment: Olá Zuul, realmente não funcionou. Não há meio de exibir o dorpdown com a opção salva no banco.

Comment: @Downbeat ?? Tem que funcionar, quando consultas algo na base de dados ficas com um _array_, o `foreach` lê cada entrada do _array_ e constrói um outro _array_ da forma que o _helper_ `form_dropdown` espera receber. Para não estar a funcionar, a única coisa que me ocorre é o que recolhes da BD não ser aquilo que estavas à espera...

Comment: Desculpe, talvez eu esteja com dificuldade de formular corretamente a pergunta. Eu preciso exibir a opção selecionada pelo usuário e gravada no banco de dados em uma página que deve retornar todos os campos do formulário para realizar um possível update dos dados. Com os outros campos eu fiz assim e funcionou:echo form_input(array('name' => 'postname'), set_value('postname', ucwords($post->postTitle)));